# CPI and real quantities

Tags: macroeconomics

How is it real wages = old wages * new cpi / old cpi? It seems this discounts back to the reference period and then multiplies out to current day. This would give us new (nominal) wages?

Comment: Indeed it does. Where does it say "real wages = old wages * new cpi / old cpi"?

Comment: https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-calculate-the-real-wage

Comment: Quora is not an appropriate source...please consult a textbook on real wage calculation.

Comment: Thought as much. Thank you, Giskard.